# How can i import Macro-enabled excel file (.xlsm) into CPLEX?

Tags: cplex

I have used VBA to randomize samples in excel, and now I would like to import my file into CPLEX. However, the file can not be found be cplex. Is there any way to import the macro file into CPLEX directly?

Answer (score 1):

SheetConnection works fine with .xlsm files

In the [Oil Example](https://www.ibm.com/docs/pl/icos/12.9.0?topic=keywords-sheetread) if you write

```
SheetConnection sheet("oilSheet.xlsm");
```

This example still works fine